# Java exception with scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with the scanner. When I compile it, there are no problems. but when I want to run this program, I get an exception. Can any of you explain me the reason of this problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CiagArytmetyczny {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner("System.in");
        System.out.println("Podaj dlugosc ciagu: ");
        int dl = s.nextInt();
        int element = 2;

        for(int i=1; i<=dl; i++) {
            element=element+3;
            System.out.println(element);

        }
    }
}
```

Podaj dlugosc ciagu:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)

    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)

    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

    at CiagArytmetyczny.main(CiagArytmetyczny.java:8)
```

Process completed.

Comment: input is enter key?

Comment: not the solution but it should be  `new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding about runtime and compile time exceptions

Comment: @FastSnail but it *is* the solution.

Comment: @Fast Why is that not a solution? The string of "System.in" has no integers

Comment: ahh sorry ......

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in this line

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner("System.in");
```

You are passing a string to the Scanner constructor. According to the java docs ([Scanner(String source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String))), a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string will be returned. According to the rest of your program, a String with a number should be provided for the scanner to pick up in the following line.

```
int dl = s.nextInt();
```

If you intend to get input from the console, Please change the scanner initialization as follows.
There are few more constructors to Scanner, I suggest you have a look at [the java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)).

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This will give the console input stream to the Scanner.